# Python Crypto installation issue

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, pycrypto

I cannot install newest Python Crypto module on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS. I removed the old 2.0.1 Crypto version with `sudo apt-get remove python-crypto` and proceeded to install version 2.6.

I downloaded newest Crypto zip and ran the installer with `sudo python setup.py install`, but I get:

```
running install  
running build  
running build_py  
running build_ext  
running build_configure  
warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.  
building 'Crypto.Cipher._AESNI' extension  
gcc -std=gnu99 -fno-strict-aliasing -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-unused-parameter -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -fPIC -Isrc/ -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c src/AESNI.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.6/src/AESNI.o -maes
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.3/include/wmmintrin.h:31,
                 from src/AESNI.c:26:  
/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.3/include/emmintrin.h: In function \u2018aes128_keyexpand\u2019:  
/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.3/include/emmintrin.h:1380: error: the last argument must be an 8-bit immediate  
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I installed `python-dev`, but it had no effect.

`apt-get install python-crypto` just installs Crypto 2.0.1.

My Python version is 2.6.5.

Answer (score 0):

If you have i.e.

```
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal main
```

in your /etc/apt/sources.list then You don't need to download zip file you can download source using apt-get source like;

```
apt-get install debhelper
apt-get source python-crypto
apt-get build-dep python-crypto

tar xvf python-crypto*debian*tar.gz
cd python-crypto*
debian/rules binary
```

You can modify your debian/rules file to add custom flags if you need before run

```
debian/rules binary
```

After build is complete you can install packages using

```
dpkg -i *.deb
```

It's also possible that your distro version doesn't meet requirements for installing latest vesion of python-crypto.

Comment: `apt-get source python-crypto` yields crypto version 2.0.1 which can be obtained by typing `apt-get install python-crypto`.

Linux environment is somewhat new to me, what I am doing wrong here?